# Use Perl regex to insert spaces into numbers

Tags: regex, perl

I have the following text data:

```
1290        15      46 
372         4       -1914 
670         8       -894 
1016        12      554
```

I am trying this to insert spaces:

```
'1290' -replace "(?<=(\d{3})),$&"
'-1914' -replace "(?<=(\d{3})),$&"
```

These regexps don't work.

The output I need:

```
1 290
```

or:

```
-1 914
```

Comment: [Number::Format](http://p3rl.org/Number::Format)

Comment: @choroba, thanks for your reply! but i was not able to install Number::Format. I have windows, so i would us regex. (also also xml::Twig i was unable to instal this module. greats @r

Comment: How did you try to install it? What error did you get?

Comment: @Choroba, Thanks for your reply. I m not in remember. but i will do evinig and i open en news topic. at this moment i would so: .format_picture($number, '## ### ### ###') ????? greats @r

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following regex:

```
(\d)(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))
```

See [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/yY0iH3/1) and [IDEONE demo](https://ideone.com/wcQCQJ)

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
# your code goes here
my $ins = "1290        15      46\n372         4       -1914\n670         8       -894\n1016        12      554";
$ins =~ s/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/$1 /g;
print "$ins\n";
```

Output:

```
1 290        15      46
372          4       -1 914
670          8       -894
1 016        12      554
```

Comment: @Arnold: What do you mean? [Here is an example code for `14589965321`](https://ideone.com/3cfFsL). My regex works as expected. And regex101.com is working well in my browser, [here is a demo](https://regex101.com/r/mY3fF0/1).

Comment: soorry "1. 1. " my error. all ist the beste Many thanks to Polska!! @r

Comment: You are welcome. Please consider also upvoting if my answer proved useful to you. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following to match:

```
(?<=\d)(?=(\d{3}))
```

And replace with `[ ]` (space)

See [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/kQ3vQ0/2)

Comment: [Here it will fail](https://regex101.com/r/kQ3vQ0/3).

Comment: @stribizhev I knew someone would point that out.. I must say.., unclear question!

Comment: Hi to all. many thanks for your reply! The stuff from @stribiz works fin, but not individuelle. iha have used: oderwise with padre " #!/usr/bin/perl

my $ins = "14589965321";
$ins =~ (?<=\d)(?<=(\d{3}));
print "$ins\n";

This is unmatched. please i need ifo wy?

Comment: @stribiz i can see :You seem to be using an outdated version of your browser which is no longer supported by regex101.com. It is highly recommended that you upgrade your browser. Sorry for the inconvenience.